# How to create a column that starts with and end with string value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

How do I create a column that starts from "\"" and ends in "]" in another column?

For example

```
A                  new_column

\\loc\ggg.x]ddj    \\loc\ggg.x]
+\\lol\lll.d]aaa   \\lol\lll.d]
```

I tried doing this

```
df['new_column'] = df['A'].str.split(']').str[0]
```

but it included unneeded text and want to only start at X (\) and end with Y ("]").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.str.extract`:

```py
df["new_column"] = df["A"].str.extract(r"(\\.*?\])")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                                       A                 new_column
0                                                                        \\loc\ggg.x]ddj               \\loc\ggg.x]
1                                                                       +\\lol\lll.d]aaa               \\lol\lll.d]
2  \\ddf\gdd\Ps\s\3\s[a.xls]ss'!e+'\\d\\P\2\d[d.xls]Canjet'!B42+'\\df\gds\+'\\s\P[s.pdf]  \\ddf\gdd\Ps\s\3\s[a.xls]
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I now came across is some strings add to each other . For example  "\\ddf\gdd\Ps\s\3\s\[a.xls]ss'!e+'\\d\\P\2\d\[d.xls]Canjet'!B42+'\\df\gds\+'\\s\P\[s.pdf]" and it’s not returning only \\ddf\gdd\Ps\s\3\s\[a.xls] but more than I wanted.

Comment: @helpme See my edit. (use the pattern `r"(\\.*?\])"`)

Comment: worked perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.replace` here with a capture group:

```py
df["new_column"] = df["A"].str.replace(r'^.*?(\\\\.*\]).*$', r'\1')
```